# Swift Array - transforming each item into an object and return new array with tranformed objects

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, transform

Suppose I have a struct like :

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var photo: String
}
```

And an array using the struct :

```
let persons = [
    Person(name: "John", photo: "john.png"),
    Person(name: "Mike", photo: "mike.png"),
    Person(name: "Skye", photo: "skye.png")
]
```

I want to create an array extension in Swift that is the shorthand way of the following :

```
let newPersons = persons.map { person -> Person in
    var temp = person
    temp.photo = "http://server/uploads/\(temp.photo)"
    return temp
}
```

I don't want to declare a copy of the person object, transform the desired field and return new object in the map closure param.

Comment: I think you might be solving the wrong problem. It's probably better to just make a computed property on `Person` which returns `photoURL: URL`, based off `baseURL.appendingPathComponent(self.photoName)`

Comment: Like this: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/e4879b5096580bd344fd374c77af0c7d